# dataWithContentsOfURL returns The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)

Tags: ios, nsdata

I have found other questions similar but they do not solve my problem.

Here is my code

```
    NSURL *audioUrlValidation   = [NSURL URLWithString:[sender objectAtIndex:1]];

DLog(@"audio validate nsurl %@", audioUrlValidation);

    NSError* error = Nil;
NSData *data            = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:audioUrlValidation options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];

    if (nil != error) {
        DLog(@"Connection failed! Error %@ - %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
    DLog(@"response data %@", data);

NSString *audioValidationResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

error that i get

```
audio validate nsurl  NSURL=http://www.mydomain.com/returntexthtml.php

Connection failed! Error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)" UserInfo=0x98b4680 {NSURL=http://www.mydomain.com/returntexthtml.php}

response data (null)
```

I know error code 256 is NSFileReadUnknownError, THIS error code does not help at all.

My URL has http:// so that is not the issue either?

The following are the response headers to the request

```
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  28
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Tue, 02 Oct 2012 06:54:58 GMT
Server  nginx
Vary    Accept-Encoding
```

What could be going wrong?

Comment: You're not even using the URL you make....you are using something called "audioUrlValidation"

Comment: Also, you should never test for error conditions in cocoa frameworks by testing if error is set. Instead, follow the documentation, if data is nil, then there is an error condition and error will be set. If data is not nil, there was not an error condition and the state of error is undefined.

Comment: @Jason, data is nil, that is why I added a check for error

Comment: @borrden if i was using the audioUrlValidation, then how come the error has the correct URL in the error object, thanks for downvoting my question!!!!

Comment: @Jason, if you did see the output i was getting you would haev noticed that data is NULL!!! so even though i didn't check for it, i still am getting it NULL, and that is my problem. WHY am I getting it null

Comment: I'm saying you shouldn't check error in general, you should check data. Obviously this isn't really your code since I already fixed one issue that would have prevented this code from compiling and @borrrden pointed out the variable names didn't even match. We can't help you debug a random issue if you don't at least provide the actual code you're using.

Comment: @JasonCoco I have added my actual code now, I modified it earlier to confuse you less. Hope the actual compilable code helps you in helping me

Comment: I have replaced my actual domain with mydomain in the output